# Why byte works slower than int? class instantiation

Tags: java, performance

I have this simple code. If I change int to byte in MyClass then it works 1.5 slower for some reason. Any idea, why?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MyClass[] arr = new MyClass[10_000_000];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new MyClass();
    }

    double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    }
}
class MyClass {
    final public int pole = 50;
    int eshePole;
}
```

Comment: *If I change int to byte in MyClass then it works 1.5 slower for some reason* .. Are you talking about `pole` and `eshePole` variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380696/java-short-integer-long-performance

Comment: it works 1.5 **what** slower?

Comment: @Ingo 1.5 times slower, I assume

Comment: it works 1.5 times slower

Comment: Run under a profiler to see exactly where the time is spent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's difficult to trust the results from a test like this, as you haven't done any warmup to allow the JVM to do things like optimise code paths.  It's worth looking at articles like:

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/MicroBenchmarks

Your test is also incorrect as `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long, not a double.