# Is it worth converting 64bit integers to 32bit (of 16bit) ints in a spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that contains ~4bn records. Many of the columns are 64bit ints, but could be truncated into 32bit or 16bit ints without data loss. When I try converting the data types using the following function:

```
def switchType(df, colName):
    df = df.withColumn( colName + "SmallInt", df[colName].cast(ShortType()))
        df = df.drop(colName)
        return df.withColumnRenamed(colName + 'SmallInt', colName)

positionsDf = switchType(positionsDf, "FundId")
# repeat for 4 more cols...
print(positionsDf.cache().count())
```

This shows as taking 54.7 MB in ram. When I don't do this, it shows as 56.7MB in ram.

So, is it worth trying to truncate ints at all?

I am using Spark 2.01 in stand alone mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to write it in format that saves numbers in binary (parquet, avro) it may save some space. For calculations there will be probably no difference in speed.

Comment: Doesn't Spark take advantage of SSE and similar instructions?

Comment: Spark uses only what JVM can give. In case of Java there is no really speed boost by changing numerical types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380696/java-short-integer-long-performance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for the benefit of anyone else that stumbles across this. If I understand it, it depends on your JVM implementation (so, machine/OS specific), but in my case it makes little difference. I'm running java 1.8.0_102 on RHEL 7 64bit.

I tried it with a larger dataframe (3tn+ records). The dataframe contains 7 coulmns of type short/long, and 2 as doubles:

- As longs - 59.6Gb
- As shorts - 57.1Gb

The tasks I used to create this cached dataframe also showed no real difference in execution time.

What *is* nice to note is that the storage size does seem to scale linearly with the number of records. So that is good.